# Rewrite promises function into async function

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm trying to rewrite promises function into async function

While my promises work

```
function boxColor (time) {
return new Promise ((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        res(box.style.backgroundColor = randomColor())
    }, time)

})}
```

I can't make it work with async

```
async function newBoxColor(time) {
try {
    setTimeout(() =>{
        return box.style.backgroundColor = randomColor()
    }, time)
} catch (error) {
    throw error
} }
```

What is my mistake here?

Comment: Both are wrong.

Comment: can you give more context?

Comment: There's no point, you'll need to wrap the timeout into a promise anyway so async/await would just add an unnecessary extra layer.

Answer (score 1):

The `async` keyword has two effects:

1. It makes the function return a promise which resolves to the value returned from the function (your function doesn't have a `return` statement so that is `undefined`; the return value of the arrow function passed to `setTimeout` is in a different function).
2. It allows you to use the `await` keyword inside that function to make it go to sleep while waiting for another promise to resolve

It is a tool to **manage existing promises**. It isn't helpful in converting a function which expects a callback to one which returns a promise.

You need to continue to use `new Promise` to get a Promise which resolves after `setTimeout` is done.